# Methodology to create black and white wall mural?

Tags: walls, desk, wallpaper

I recently stumbled upon a wall mural (I believe that's what it's called anyway), that I found after researching some desks. I would very much like to emulate this style of wall mural found behind the desk and computer. Could anyone tell me the best way I might go about re-creating this sort of effect?

[image: WallImage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photograph, large format printer, gator-board, dry-mount press, your favorite wall attachment hardware. The mural is panelized and the seams are visible in the image.

Comment: Just was I was looking for - concise and clear. Thank you!